# How to limit a chrome extension to one tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs

I have a extension that does random bing searches.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){   
var a = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
chrome.tabs.update(tabId,{'url': "http://www.bing.com/search?q=" + a});

var x = 0;
var intervalID = setInterval(function(){

    a = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
    chrome.tabs.update({'url': "http://www.bing.com/search?q=" + a});

    // how many times it should work 
    if(++x === 7){
        window.clearInterval(intervalID);
    }
},5000); // this is the delay, in milliseconds
```

});

The problem is that this will do searches on the current tab. So if I switch tabs or open a new window, it does a search on my current tab. I want it to continue on the tab it had started on.

My solution was to pass in a tabId into chrome.tabs.update. However, the problem I am having is I can't figure out how to get the tab.id of the previous tab. How can I fix this problem?

Thanks for the help!

--- my attempted fix:

```
var tabId;

chrome.tabs.query(
  {currentWindow: true, active : true},
  function(tabArray){
    tabId = tab.id;
  }
);

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){   
var a = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
chrome.tabs.update(tabId,{'url': "http://www.bing.com/search?q=" + a});

var x = 0;
var intervalID = setInterval(function(){

    a = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
    chrome.tabs.update(tabId,{'url': "http://www.bing.com/search?q=" + a});

    // how many times it should work (after the first one initially
    if(++x === 3){
        window.clearInterval(intervalID);
    }
},5000); // this is the delay
```

});